# Unable to wait for multiple AJAX calls to finish

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to send files to my API and want to do it one by one when multiple files are selected and use two different Post calls

In `click` event I get the files and loop through them then pass the file data to `First()` function call to get back the Unique Id (`VersionID`) and pass that `VersionID` when making the second call to `second()` function.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar">0%</div>
    </div>    
    <div id="status"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
            var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;               
            var status = $('#status');
            $('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () {
                $("#btnUploadFile").attr("disabled", true);
                var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
                var input = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
                for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
                    var file = input.files[i];
                    first(9, file.name, (file.size / 1000), file.name.split('.')[1], function (versionID) {
                        $.when(second(versionID, files[i])).done(function(){
                            status.html('Uploading ' + i + ' of ' + input.files.length)});                        
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

**First Call**

```
function first(libid, filename, filesize, fileextension, callback) {
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("LibId", libid);
            form.append("FileName", filename);
            form.append("FileSize", filesize);
            form.append("FileExtension", fileextension);
            var settings = {
                "async": false,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "URL",
                "method": "POST",                  
                "processData": false,
                "contentType": false,
                "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                "data": form
            }
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                callback(response);
            });
        };
```

**Second call**

```
function second(versionId, fileData) {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('UploadedFiles', fileData);
            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var percent = $('.progress-bar');            
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "URL" + Math.floor(versionId).toString(),
                method: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                data: data,                    
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    xhr.onprogress = function e() {
                        // For downloads
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                        // For uploads
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {                            
                            var percentVal = parseInt((e.loaded / e.total * 100), 10);
                            console.log("Loaded " + parseInt((e.loaded / e.total * 100), 10) + "%");
                            var percentValue = percentVal + '%';
                            bar.width(percentValue);
                            percent.html(percentValue);                            
                        }
                    };
                    return xhr;
                }
            }).done(function (response) {                
                percent.html("Completed");                 
            }).fail(function (e) {
                console.log("failed");
            });
        };
```

The issue is `$.when(second(versionID, files[i])).done....` does not seem to wait before continuing the loop.

**Current Behaviour:**

> It waits for the `First()` function to finish and then triggers
>   `Sencond()` function but does not wait for `Second()` function before
>   starting the new `First()` function.

**Expected Behaviour**

> Wait for the `First()` function to fully finish and then wait for the
>   `Second()` function to fully complete also before looping back to next
>   file and call `First()` function again.

The other thing I am using `async: false` in `First()` function and `async: true` in `Second()` function as if I don't use `async: true` in `Second()` function, I cant get file upload progress.

Is it possible to wait for `second()` function to finish before continuing the loop while using AJAX `async: true`?

Comment: You need to make `second()` return the jqXHR object from the async call for `$.done()` to work; eg `return $.ajax({...`. I also note that while you've intentionally made this in to multiple sync calls, it's not a great idea for a variety of reasons, the most pressing of which is scalability, data integrity and user experience. I'd strongly suggest you aggregate all data and make a call to a single endpoint.

Comment: in your `second` `async`is still true - it retrurns immediately. Is that intended?

Comment: `"async": false,` — This is deprecated. Don't do that.

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` — This is pointless unless you are making a same-origin request that gets redirected to be a cross-origin request (which is really weird and unlikely).

Comment: `mimeType: "multipart/form-data",` — This is just wrong (the boundary parameter is missing). The only reason it doesn't break your file upload is because you used `contentType` too and that overrides it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I hate that too, The reason I had to do this was to avoid sending files to API unless they are valid files (without loading them to MemoryStream/FileStream in API) and to avoid a situation when a file is sent to API (fully uploaded by client) then loaded into MemoryStream for validation checks and then uploaded to Azure Storage (3 steps process, double of data pass-through) therefore a tiny first call was made to sort out the complex validation mechanism and only send file when is valid (API is public so everything had to go through the API, no direct client-side actions)

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for all the suggestions, I copied it from Postman with a bunch of properties Postman attaches with a request, I should be more careful what to keep and what to discard when copying from Postman

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan return $.ajax... does not seem to make it wait also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, `when` needs to be passed one or more *thenable objects*, but you are passing `undefined`. `second` has no return statement. There's no point in using `when` though, because you aren't running multiple functions in parallel.

The second problem is that while `when` won't call the `done` callback until everything you pass to it is done … the `for` loop **will not wait** for the `when` to complete.

---

There are two approaches you can do to solve this problem:

1. Remove the `for` loop

   - Keep `var i`
   - Have `first` increment `i`
   - Call `first` recursively from `second` (until `i` is `input.files.length`)
2. Use `async` / `await` to manage the promises returned from `$.ajax` (which will let you keep the loop).

The latter approach will require the use of a transpiler like Babel if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: The first approach sounds good, Let me give it a try :) Thanks for the reply